# Storeing user's last login timestamp

Tags: sql, codeigniter

### Important Edit: There was not a programming error

That was a mistake by me and resulted to the problem. Please read the problem below:

---

I want to update user's last login's timestamp after I see that the user has logged in with below `login()` function at `user_model.php`.

```
public function login($username, $password)
{

    $this->db->select('id, username, email, type, language, lastlogintimestamp');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $result = $this->db->get();

    if ($result->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $this_user = $result->first_row();

        $this->db->query(
            'UPDATE `user` SET `lastlogintimestamp` = ? WHERE `id` = ? LIMIT 1',
            array(time(), $this_user->id)
        );

        return $this_user;
    }

    return FALSE;

}
```

After the user has logged in successfully, `$result->first_row()` is stored into `$this_user` variable and **after that** I update the `lastlogintimestamp`.

So it's obvious that **the old value of `lastlogintimestamp`** should be returned.

**THE PROBLEM** is that very strangely I see that the new value is returned!!!

---

Very simple: Where I was seeing the result, was because of a very separate query like `SELECT * FROM user`.

There, I was seeing a list of users with their own `lastlogintimestamp`s.

It's clear that I was seeing the updated `lastlogintimestamp`s.

Anyway I should thank [**Prix**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/342740) for helping me find the problem via the comments. I think that the best I can do now with this question, is voting for it be close.

Comment: Better yet use `NOW()` like this: `UPDATE \`user\` SET \`lastlogintimestamp\` = NOW() WHERE \`id\` = ? AND \`username\` = ? LIMIT 1` and then you can remove time() from the array as it is not needed.

Comment: [**`NOW()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) will get you the current timestamps its a MySQL function.

Comment: No, no, my answer was for a comment that has now been deleted. OK, I'll try the new way. But `1.` why shouldn't current query do the work? `2.` Does MySQL's `NOW()`, return a UTC timestamp, too?

Comment: No, as the docs say, MySQL's `NOW()` is returned in the server's timezone. But I want to store every timestamp in `UTC timezone`.

Comment: Also you don't need to use `AND \`username\` = ?` if your id is a primary key. Yes should would return the same as time unless it contains a different internal time set because time also returns the server's timezone unless you had manually changed it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `AND `username` = ?` is not a must and I delete it.

Comment: Is there any other code that could be reading the lastlogintimestamp after you login that could possible be updating it ? Have you tried to echo it before the update and after within your function to see if the values differ ?

Comment: You should be right dear Prix, because when I `var_dump($this_user)` both after and before the `UPDATE` query, the old timestamp is returned. There should be an override after the function returns its output. I'm still looking for it. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome;) hope you punish the bad boy.

Comment: The problem was that I only looked at my own account's `lastlogintimestamp` in the user list. My bad, the list was of course generated with a whole new query like `SELECT * FROM user` and it of course returned everything correctly with the last updated values! Thank you anyway. Please guide me as an answer so that I can accept it. Thank you once again `:)`

Comment: Well I didn't do anything here to be fairly honest, I just pointed you on the right direction so I guess you could post the above comment as an answer and mark it to close this question down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the comments of my question, I got what I was doing wrong.

I should again thank [**@Prix**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/342740/prix) for putting me in the right direction as he said in the last comment. (Read [**THIS comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643713/storeing-users-last-login-timestamp#comment25692689_17643713) and the next 3 ones)

I voted to close the question and accept it as an answer to be unanswered not.